# How to make dynamic creation of various charts at the same page?

Tags: javascript, java, highcharts, dinamico

I need to create a screen (web application) that will be arranged around 30 small graphs, each with two series of data;
These graphs need to be dynamically updated once every minute with data coming from the database.

What would be the best approach to create something like this?

What is the best way to "draw" these graphics on the page given that I know Javascript, servlet, java and html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a broad, subjective question. One approach is to add all your charts to the page on load, poll the server for new data every minute, and update the charts with the results. You've tagged Highcharts, and they have an example showing exactly what you're trying to do: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Comment: My problem is to drawn the graphs, and split the objects on each graph.... i am doing one by one at the front-end, but will be more interesting if i could to make it at the back - end.

Comment: @Jovani Typically the functionality you described is done on the front end because that allows the user to experience the updates much more quickly and facilitates interactive charts - which is what Highcharts is good at. If you want to have the server build an image containing 30 new sub-images every minute, you will find it to take a lot of processing and you will not be able to properly display charts based on the user's screen size.

Comment: Ok, thanks by  the help!!